# Google Maps no muestra coordenadas correctas JQueryMobile

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, app

estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android que usa las API de Google Maps. La forma de invocar y dibujar los mapas es con Jquery mobile. 
La función es la siguiente:

```
       function mapas(opc) {




        $(document).on("pageinit", "#map-page", function () {
                  if (opc = 1) {
                    alert('opcion 1');
                    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.384716, -0.510933); 
                } else if (opc = 2) {
                    alert('opcion 2');
                    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.384716, -0.510933);  
                }
               drawMap(defaultLatLng);
                function drawMap(latlng) {
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 14,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
                    // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: "Greetings!"
                    });

            });`
```

Donde `#map-page` es el ID del div que forma la página y `#map-canvas` es la ID del div donde se dibujará el mapa.
El caso es que cuando invoco esta función tal y como aparece con `opc=1`, muestra el mapa como toca. 
Por otro lado, quiero que pulsando un botón, muestre las coordenadas de otro sitio, invoco la función `mapas(2)` , sin embargo, vuelve a dibujar el mapa con las coordenadas de la opción 1.

¿Por qué puede pasar esto?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

bienvenid@ a SOes, espero te sea de utilidad:

```
 if (opc = 1) {
...
 } else if (opc = 2) {
```

Reemplaza por:

```
 if (opc === 1) {
...
 } else if (opc === 2) {
```

A tener en cuenta en JavaScript:

https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Era ese el error, vaya tontería. Has sido de gran ayuda!

Comment: de nada :D acepta la respuesta haciendo click en el check verde y ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas respondidas).